Change log level of DeadLetterPublishingRecovererFactory with spring-kafka
I set up message sending with exponential retries via kafka with spring-kafka (3.0.13). Everything is ok but when all the retries have been executed there is a log with the ERROR level when the message is posted on the dlt topic.
2024-06-05T16:35:56.647+02:00 ERROR 16128 --- [etry-2000-0-C-1] k.r.DeadLetterPublishingRecovererFactory : Record: topic = ORDER-retry-2000, partition = 1, offset = 5, main topic = ORDER threw an error at topic ORDER-retry-2000 and won't be retried. Sending to DLT with name ORDER-dlt.
I would like to modify the log level of this "error" but I can't find how to do it.
I tried to modify the log level on the DefaultErrorHandler class but it seems that this is not the right place to do that.
EDIT:
here is my configuration for exponentials retries:
configuration:
@Bean
fun webhookRetryTopic() = RetryTopicConfigurationBuilder
    .newInstance()
    .autoCreateTopics(true, partition, replicationFactor.toShort())
    .maxAttempts(webhookBackOffProperties.attempts)
    .exponentialBackoff(
        webhookBackOffProperties.initialInterval * 1000L,
        webhookBackOffProperties.multiplier.toDouble(),
        webhookBackOffProperties.maxInterval * 1000L
    )
    .sameIntervalTopicReuseStrategy(SameIntervalTopicReuseStrategy.SINGLE_TOPIC)
    .includeTopics(KafkaConfiguration.webhookTopics)
    .retryOn(KafkaRetryableException::class.java)
    .dltProcessingFailureStrategy(DltStrategy.FAIL_ON_ERROR)
    .dltHandlerMethod(EndpointHandlerMethod(KafkaWebhookDltHandler::class.java, "dlt"))
    .create(kafkaTemplate)

Listener:
 companion object {
        val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(KafkaWebhookConsumerService::class.java)
        const val WEBHOOK_GROUP = "WEBHOOK"
        const val CONTAINER_FACTORY = "webhookKafkaListenerContainerFactory"
    }

    @KafkaListener(
        topics = [PRODUCT_TOPIC, COUPON_TOPIC, CUSTOMER_TOPIC, ORDER_TOPIC, STOCK_MOVEMENT_TOPIC, PREPAID_CARD_TOPIC,
                 CUSTOMER_ADDRESS_TOPIC],
        containerFactory = CONTAINER_FACTORY,
        groupId = WEBHOOK_GROUP
    )
    fun handleMessage(record: ConsumerRecord<String, KafkaMessageWrapper>) {
        val messageWrapper = record.value()

        val entity = messageWrapper.entity

        val id = messageWrapper.id

        val additionalData = messageWrapper.additionalData

        val stringMessage = kafkaObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(record.value())

        val event = record.headers().headers("event").firstOrNull()?.let { String(it.value()) }

        val topic = record.headers().headers("topic").firstOrNull()?.let { String(it.value()) }
            ?: throw KafkaNotRetryableException("No topic on kafka message for message $stringMessage - event: ${event ?: "NO_EVENT"}")

        val instanceId = record.headers().headers("instanceId").firstOrNull()?.let { String(it.value()) }
            ?: throw KafkaNotRetryableException("No instanceId on kafka message for message $stringMessage on topic $topic - event: ${event ?: "NO_EVENT"}")


        if (event == KafkaMessageWrapper.DELETE && id == null) {
            throw KafkaNotRetryableException("id can not be null if event is ${KafkaMessageWrapper.DELETE} on topic $topic - message: $stringMessage")
        }
        if (event != KafkaMessageWrapper.DELETE && entity == null) {
            throw KafkaNotRetryableException("entity can not be null if event is not ${KafkaMessageWrapper.DELETE} on topic $topic - message: $stringMessage")
        }

        InstanceContextHolder.setInstanceId(instanceId)

        val instance = instanceService.getCurrentInstance()

        val secretKey = instance.webhookSecretKey
            ?: throw KafkaNotRetryableException("no webhook secret key on instance")

        val stringContent = if (event == KafkaMessageWrapper.DELETE) {
            kafkaObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(WebhookIdMessage(id = id!!, additionalData = additionalData))
        } else {
            kafkaObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(entity)
        }

        val contentHash = try {
            val webhookSecretKey = SecretKeySpec(secretKey.toByteArray(charset("UTF-8")),
                "HmacSHA256")
            val mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256").apply { init(keybuildWebhookSecretKey) }
            String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(mac.doFinal(stringContent.toByteArray())))
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            throw KafkaNotRetryableException(e)
        }

        val webhook = webhookService.findByTopic(topic)
            ?: throw KafkaNotRetryableException("No webhook found for $topic to send message $stringContent")

        if(webhook.broken) {
            throw KafkaNotRetryableException("Webhook ${webhook.id} is broken - $stringContent not sent on topic $topic")
        }


        val headers = HttpHeaders().apply {
            set("instanceId", instanceId)
            contentType = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON
        }

        val content = if (event == KafkaMessageWrapper.DELETE) {
            WebhookContentWrapper(topic, contentHash, WebhookIdMessage(id = id!!, additionalData = additionalData), event, messageWrapper.timestamp)
        } else {
            WebhookContentWrapper(topic, contentHash, entity!!, event, messageWrapper.timestamp)
        }

        val response = try {
            webhookRestTemplate.exchange(webhook.url, HttpMethod.POST, HttpEntity(content, headers), Void::class.java)
        } catch (e: RestClientResponseException) {
            logger.info("rest client exception on sending, kafka retry launch")
            throw KafkaRetryableException(e)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            logger.info("rest server exception on sending, no kafka retry")
            throw KafkaNotRetryableException(e)
        }

        if (response.statusCode != HttpStatus.OK) {
            throw KafkaRetryableException("Response code is not 200")
        } else {
            logger.info("Message sent successfully for topic $topic")
            webhookService.setLastEventSentTime(webhook.id, Instant.now())
    }
}


Are you using non-blocking retries? That logging is coming from here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/blob/main/spring-kafka/src/main/java/org/springframework/kafka/retrytopic/DeadLetterPublishingRecovererFactory.java#L277. As you can see, the ERROR level is hard-coded. We could consider relaxing it, but is there a way to reproduce what you see? I tried the regular DLT functionality on a test app and this logging message is not happening when sending to DLT.

@sobychacko hi, thank you for your answer, yes these are non-blocking retries. I edited my post to add the configuration and the listener
